# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode not decoding spaces?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have this

```
 string test =  HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("http://test.com/Folder1/Folder2/my%20view.aspx");
```

When I look into test it still has %20 instead of a space. Why is it not decoding this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are looking for `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` (in the System.Web namespace, I think)

Comment: Makes sense did not even see that one. Let me try that one out.

Answer (score 3):

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode not decoding "%20", use HttpUtility.UrlDecode to decode "%20"