# Raw request body to string array

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I have the service code:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/BTNMetadata/", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<BtnMetaData> BTNMetadata()
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Expires", "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        var x= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(OperationContext.Current.RequestContext
                      .RequestMessage.GetBody<byte[]>());
```

But I found the returned `x`:

```
x=%5B%228124318066%22%2C%223869383310%22%2C%229417395507%22%5D
```

What I want is:

```
8124318066
3869383310
9417395507
```

Is there a .Net Framework encoding method to do it?

Comment: Looks like URL encoding. Decoded it's `["8124318066","3869383310","9417395507"]` which is a JSON string. There are several URL decoding methods in the .NET library.

Comment: @MattBurland, I send a string list in request. Using RestSharp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an [example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505785/httputility-htmldecode-not-decoding-spaces) Using HttpUtility.UrlDecode().

```
var x = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%5B%228124318066%22%2C%223869383310%22%2C%229417395507%22%5D");
```